# spring integration looping of orders

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Using spring integration, for every min i need to read list of orders from database whose status is in-progress and make a 3rd party rest call for each order in sequence or parallel. Below is my code

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="orderReader" method="readOrderRecords"
                               channel="orderListChannel">
    <int:poller cron="0/60 * * * * *"/>
  </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

  <int:splitter input-channel="orderListChannel" method="split" ref="orderSplitter"
                output-channel="processOrders">
  </int:splitter>

  <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="processOrders"/>

  <int:chain id="orderProcess_Chain"
             input-channel="processOrders">
      ...contain the REST call config
  </int.chain>
```

The above code is not working as expected, if there are n records in the database with in-progress, its processing only the first order (orderProcess_Chain is called only for 1st order)

What is wrong in the code

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to see your DB reading logic, that your `orderReader.readOrderRecords()`.

From the other hand you should be sure that finish your REST call properly.

It is actually request/reply protocol, but I see only one-way interaction.
Right, that is correct for your purpose, but you should `void` the REST response somehow.

And one more clue. You always can switch on `DEBUG` for the `org.springframework.integration` category and analyze how your messages travel there. For example you may have some `Exception`, but there is no any exception handling in your config.

Comment: public List<Order> readOrderRecords(); is returning list of orders and the response of REST call will update the order status. I see it working for one order.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to play here Spy Games. How about just debug your code? There is no confirmation that your `readOrderRecords()` returns many items. For example we don't know what your `orderSplitter.split()` does. Maybe it returns just only one item... And there are so much etc.. And everything just because it is your code and we, from our side, only try to take a look into he black box through the very small hole, which is being closing by you, too, with such a useless comments. Place yourself here and review your question like you aren't an author of it and even that code.